# Hibernate doesn't set actual fields values when parsing from JSON

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm building a Java Spring websocket chat and I have an endpoint, where messages are sent:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat")
public void processMessage(Message message) {
    message
            .getChat()
            .getUsers()
            .stream()
            .map(User::getId)
            .forEach(id ->
                    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                            String.valueOf(id),
                            "/queue/messages",
                            message
                    )
            );

    messageRepository.save(message);
}
```

Also I have JavaScript sendMessage function:

```
const sendMessage = (msg) => {
    const message = {
        message: msg,
        user: {
            id: 1
        },
        chat: {
            id: 1
        }
    };

    stompClient.send("/app/chat", {}, JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

Also when testing it I have 2 database entries:
postgres=# select * from chat; 
id |   name    | users_number | owner_id 
----+-----------+--------------+---------- 
1 | test_chat |            1 |        1 
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from chat_user;
 id |      email      | name | password | registration_date
----+-----------------+------+----------+-------------------
  1 | email@email.com | user | 1        | 2021-07-20
(1 row)

When processMessage receives a message it doesn't send it back, because message chat field is:

```
Chat(id=1, name=null, user=null, users=[], usersNumber=0)
```

But it must be:

```
Chat(id=1, name=test_chat, user=User(id=1, name=user, email=email@email.com, registrationDate=2021-07-20, password=1), users=[User(id=1, name=user, email=email@email.com, registrationDate=2021-07-20, password=1)], usersNumber=1)
```

I resolve it by setting message fields manually:

```
message.setChat(chatService.findChat(message.getChat().getId()));
message.setUser(userService.find(message.getUser().getId()));
```

It works, but if where is a way to do it better, like calling something like Hibernate.update(message), or maybe where is some setting to force Hibernate to update fields on parsing stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new class for the message you are receiving - a DTO so MessageDto and on the first row of `processMessage(MessageDto message)` add the following line: `Message entity = messageRepository.getById(message.getId());` And then call the chained methods on the entity and not on the dto.

It is a known practice to receive DTO-s as end point objects and use their id to get a persisted entity from the DB.

Comment: yes, that solution is better. and it would still be interesting to know about updating the object. if you know, please add in the answer.

Comment: @vszholobov I don't believe there's such a method in hibernate because to update the entity with its db data you would have to get it from the db by its id anyway so it wouldn't make much sense for them to have another method which essentially does the same thing.